# How to get the user's name in Telegram Bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm working in Telegram bot with a handler. where I need to get the user's name or users id once they use the command.

**MY CODE**

```py
import telebot  #Telegram Bot API
    
bot = telebot.TeleBot(<BotToken>)
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def send_welcome(message):
    name = bot.get_me()
    print(name)
    bot.reply_to(message, "Welcome")

bot.polling()
```

However, I get only info about the bot. I can't retrieve info about the user who used handler.

**OUTPUT**

```
{'first_name': 'SPIOTSYSTEMS', 'id': 581614234, 'username': 'spiotsystems_bot', 'is_bot': True, 'last_name': None, 'language_code': None}
```

How do I get the user id or name of the person who uses `info` command?
which method i shall use? please advise.

**NOTE:**

My bot is linked with the Telegram group. and I've removed the Telegram TOKEN from my MVC for security reasons.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `getMe()` function you are using is for getting information about the bot. But you want the name of the person who sent the message.

In the [message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) API, there is a `from` attribute (`from_user` in python) which contains a [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) object, which contains the details of the person who sent the message.

So you'll have more luck with something like `name = message.from_user.first_name`.

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
message.from_user.id
message.from_user.first_name
message.from_user.last_name
message.from_user.username
```

or read this
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user

Answer (score 2):

Access the user's `first_name` via `message` param passed with the method wich has the [`Message`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html) object, which then can access the [`Chat`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chat.html#telegram.Chat) object, getting you the name via `message.chat.first_name`, as shown in the example below with the `greet` method:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['Start'])
def greet(message):
  user_first_name = str(message.chat.first_name) 
  bot.reply_to(message, f"Hey! {user_first_name} \n Welcome To The...")
```

Comment: Hello! Answers with just a piece of code are not the best. Edit your answer and explain what does the new code will do.